# Bind9 Has no NS records and Not loaded due to errors

Tags: ubuntu, bind, reverse-dns

This is my config

Zone file

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ubuntu. root.Lordi.local. (
                         201806282      ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
ubuntu  IN      NS      Lordi.local.
ubuntu  IN      A       192.168.60.70
Lordi.local     IN      A       192.168.60.70
;@      IN      AAAA    ::1
```

Named.conf.local

```
//
// Do any local configuration here
//

// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";

// Zona de pesquisa direta
zone "Lordi.local" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.Lordi.local"; };

// Zona de Pesquisa reversa
zone  "0.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.192"; };
```

Systemctl status

```
 [ bind9.service - BIND Domain Name Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bind9.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2018-06-28 15:24:40 -03; 4 days ago
     Docs: man:named(8)
  Process: 21608 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/rndc stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 16242 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/rndc reload (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
 Main PID: 21612 (named)
    Tasks: 5 (limit: 4664)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bind9.service
           └─21612 /usr/sbin/named -f -u bind
```

Log

```
jun 28 15:24:41 ubuntu named[21612]: zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
jun 28 15:24:41 ubuntu named[21612]: zone 127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
jun 28 15:24:41 ubuntu named[21612]: zone 0.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded seri
jun 28 15:24:41 ubuntu named[21612]: zone 255.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
jun 28 15:24:41 ubuntu named[21612]: zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 2
jun 28 15:24:41 ubuntu named[21612]: zone Lordi.local/IN: has no NS records
jun 28 15:24:41 ubuntu named[21612]: zone Lordi.local/IN: not loaded due to erro
jun 28 15:24:41 ubuntu named[21612]: all zones loaded
jun 28 15:24:41 ubuntu named[21612]: running
jun 28 15:24:41 ubuntu named[21612]: zone 0.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: sending not]
```

Comment: The error message is accurate.  You have no nameservers for 'lordi.local', you only have one for 'ubuntu.lordi.local'. Also, you  are probably not going to get what you intend with your 'lordi.local' A record.  That'll parse as lordi.local.lordi.local.

Answer (score 2):

The following log entries point right at the problem:

```
zone Lordi.local/IN: has no NS records
zone Lordi.local/IN: not loaded due to errors
```

These indicate that the zone named `Lordi.local` has no `NS` records (at the zone apex) and that this prevents the zone from even being loaded.

Looking at the zone file you included, we see that the only `NS` record is

```
ubuntu  IN      NS      Lordi.local.
```

Ie, `ubuntu.Lordi.local.` is delegated as a separate zone to an alleged nameserver named `Lordi.local.`.
I wonder if the intention was to to specify that the nameserver for `Lordi.local.` is `ubuntu.Lordi.local.`?

Ie, maybe:

```
@  IN      NS      ubuntu
```

Either way, an `NS` record at the zone apex (specifying the nameserver for this zone, not delegating something below your zone elsewhere) is required.

Sorting out the `NS` at the apex situation should get the zone to load, but there are some other things worth noting:

The TLD `local` is reserved for [mDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) use and should never exist in regular DNS. Please use a name that you actually own, instead.

The following entry looks very suspect:

```
Lordi.local     IN      A       192.168.60.70
```

Is almost surely not what you want. This says that `Lordi.local.Lordi.local.` (sic) has the address `192.168.60.70`.

In general, any name that does not end in a dot are considered relative to the current origin (ie, the current origin is appended to any relative names when parsing the file). The origin starts out being the zone name, but can be changed by using the `$ORIGIN` directive.

Comment: my friend, thank you very much for the help, I'm very grateful